# How to authenticate to gcloud SDK with a service key without commiting the service key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm building a CI/CD pipeline with bitbucket pipelines.

I'd like the following command to run but I'd rather not have the key-file versioned.

```
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=
```

The issue is that it expects the path to a key-file. Until now an encoded version of my key-file was stored in an environment variable but I can't provide it to `gcloud auth activate-service-account` (or at least I don't know how).

What is the preferred way to authenticate to the SDK in a pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can decode the encoded keyfile..

```
$ echo $ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE > encrypted-key-file
$ base64 --decode encrypted-key-file > key-file.json
```